# C++11, using vs typedef, templatized

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, typedef, using

Instead of

```
typedef struct
{
 double x,y;
} Point;
```

C++11 supports

```
using Point = struct {double x, y;};
```

Unfortunately, this approach does not work for the type T

```
template <typename T>
using Point = struct {T x, y;};
```

Is there any way of resolving the problem?

Comment: but  ... but why ... why would you want to do that anyway? Even your original `typedef` is pointless (slightly ironic given the name).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`using Point = ...;` is a type alias (formally called just 'alias'). I.e., it's just a different syntax for `typedef` where the type involved is named in `...`.

`template<typename T> using Point = ...;` is an alias *template*, where the type involved is again named in `...`.

What both aliases and alias templates have in common is that both must refer to a *type-id* (C++11 [basic.scope.pdecl]p3). Type-ids must in turn name *types*. (Go figure.)

*The* problem is that `template<typename T> struct {T x, y;}` is not a type, but a class template, and as just established alias templates must refer to types. As to changing your code to resolve *your* problem, I've no idea as you haven't said what it is... ;-] Regarding that, please see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/166663)

Comment: @ ildjarn: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Is there a reason as to why you want to use a type alias in this case?
If it's to avoid prepending the `struct` keyword, this is not the case in C++.

You would just define them directly: `struct Point { double x, y; };`.

Same with the template case:

```
template <typename T>
struct Point { T x, y; };
```

Answer (score 0):

I somewhat disagree with the language lawyering in other answers, so I've decided to write my own.

In short, you cannot use
`template <typename T> using Point = struct {T x, y;};` for the same reason you cannot use `template <typename T> struct {T x, y;};`.

Alias template is still a template. And although the standard doesn't state this explicitly, it implies that a template should have a name (see [temp]/4 - *A template name has linkage ...*). Which you don't provide.

So no, you cannot "resolve the problem" without providing a name. But you also cannot just throw a name in an alias-declaration like this: `template <typename T> using Point = struct P {T x, y;};`. The standard explicitly forbids it ([dcl.typedef]/2 - *The defining-type-specifier-seq of the defining-type-id shall not define a class or enumeration*).

The only thing you can do will look something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Point {T x, y;};
template <typename T>
using PointAlias = Point<T>;
```

Which, as you can see, is pointless (unless, of course, your `Point` takes several template arguments; in this case, you can make a nifty alias template).

So stick with simple `template <typename T> struct Point {T x, y;};`. It does exactly the same thing as your "proposed" syntax.